# Extracting objects with image-difference

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, object-detection

Working on object detection in Python with opencv.

I have two pictures

1. The reference picture with no object in it.

[image: Picture One]

2. Picture with object.

[image: Picture Two]

3. The result of the images is:

[image: Result picture]

The problem is, the pattern of the reference image is now on my objects. I want  to remove this pattern and I don't know how to do it. For further image processing I need the the correct outline of the objects.
Maybe you know how to fix it, or have better ideas to exctract the object. 
I would be glad for your help.

Edit: 4. A black object:

[image: Picture with black object]

Comment: Take your difference image and blur it and threshold it, till it makes a good mask, then use that mask to reload from your object image.

Answer (score 2):

As [@Mark Setchell commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51559640/extracting-objects-with-image-difference#comment90089527_51559640), the difference of the two images shows which pixels contain the object, you shouldn't try to use it as the output. Instead, find the pixels with a significant difference, and then read those pixels directly from the input image.

Here, I'm using Otsu thresholding to find what "significant difference" is. There are many other ways to do this. I then use the inverse of the mask to blank out pixels in the input image.

```
import PyDIP as dip

bg = dip.ImageReadTIFF('background.tif')
bg = bg.TensorElement(1)   # The image has 3 channels, let's use just the green one
fg = dip.ImageReadTIFF('object.tif')
fg = fg.TensorElement(1)

mask = dip.Abs(bg - fg)               # Difference between the two images
mask, t = dip.Threshold(mask, 'otsu') # Find significant differences only
mask = dip.Closing(mask, 7)           # Smooth the outline a bit
fg[~mask] = 0                         # Blank out pixels not in the mask
```

[image]

I'm using PyDIP above, not OpenCV, because I don't have OpenCV installed. You can easily do the same with OpenCV.

An alternative to smoothing the binary mask as I did there, is to smooth the `mask` image before thresholding, for example with `dip.Gauss(mask,[2])`, a Gaussian smoothing.

**Edit:** The black object.

What happens with this image, is that its illumination has changed significantly, or you have some automatic exposure settings in your camera. Make sure you have turned all of that off so that every image is exposed exactly the same, and that you use the raw images directly off of the camera for this, not images that have gone through some automatic enhancement procedure or even JPEG compression if you can avoid it.

I computed the median of the background image divided by the object image (`fg` in the code above, but for this new image), which came up to 1.073. That means that the background image is 7% brighter than the object image. I then multiplied `fg` by this value before computing the absolute difference:

```
mask = dip.Abs(fg * dip.Median(bg/fg)[0][0] - bg)
```

This helped a bit, but it showed that the changes in contrast are not consistent across the image.

Next, you can change the threshold selection method. Otsu assumes a bimodal histogram, and works well if you have a significant number of pixels in each group (foreground and background). Here we'll have fewer pixels belonging to the object, because only some of the object pixels have a different color from the background. The `'triangle'` method is suitable in this case:

```
mask, t = dip.Threshold(mask, 'triangle')
```

This will lead to a mask that contains only some of the object pixels. You'll have to add some additional knowledge about your object (i.e. it is a rotated square) to find the full object. There are also some isolated background pixels that are being picked up by the threshold, those are easy to eliminate using a bit of blurring before the threshold or a small opening after.

Getting the exact outline of the object in this case will be impossible with your current setup. I would suggest you improve your setup by either:

- making the background more uniform in illumination,
- using color (so that there are fewer possible objects that match the background color so exactly as in this case),
- using infrared imaging (maybe the background could have different properties from all the objects to be detected in infrared?),
- using back-illumination (this is the best way if your aim is to measure the objects).

Comment: This works wonderful! Thank you for that. I've made the experience that this works well on with object that have a high contrast to the background. Objects that have the same color as the background are not detected well. Do you have any ideas for this? Is there some sort of contrast enhacement that works? I add  an image with an black object in the question.

Comment: @rexrayne: are you expecting magic? I can’t see that object’s outline, and I don’t expect a computer to do so with your setup. If you want to see such small changes in intensity, you need to make sure that the background stays 100% identical. That is highly unlikely to be possible. A much easier solution is to find a background that is more uniform in intensity, and doesn’t match the intensity of objects you’re looking for, or go to a colored background and a color camera, which will give you a much larger range of things you can detect.

Comment: You're right. It is indeed a hard task. I can't change the environment settings. So I have to deal with it and make the best out of it. I'm not looking for an perfect solution, just for ideas that  could worth a shot. I'm now trying something with CLAHE( contrast limited adaptive histogram equalization), maybe this is a way.

Comment: @rexrayne: Your background is patterned, you might be able to get something out of that. I'm not sure CLAHE is going to do what you want, it just makes existing differences better visible to the human eye, it won't make a difference for the thresholding.